# how to make different objects of a factory in factoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

Factory for User model

```
factory :user do
  name Faker::Name.name
  provider 'facebook'
  provider_user_id '1232'
  email Faker::Internet.email
 encrypted_password Faker::Internet.password
 end
```

This is factory for photo model, and it uses object of user model.

```
factory :photo do
user  FactoryGirl.create(:user)
image Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.join(Rails.root,'spec','GIV_jpg_file_small.jpg')
end
```

Now in comment factory we are creating object of both user and photo. But photo also have 
object of user. So factoryGirl is giving the same user object to both photo and comment objects. But my requirement is that I need different object of users. One user object for photo factory and one user object for comment factory.

```
factory :comment do
 user 
 photo
 content Faker::Lorem.paragraph
 end
end
```

So can anyone help me in this regard?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should NOT run FactoryGirl definitions inside of factories.

```
factory :user do
  name Faker::Name.name
  provider 'facebook'
  provider_user_id '1232'
  email Faker::Internet.email
  encrypted_password Faker::Internet.password
end 

factory :photo do
  user  
  image
end

factory :comment do
  user 
  photo
  content Faker::Lorem.paragraph
end
```

And now in your test suite, you can do something like this:

```
user1 = create(:user) # Or FactoryGirl.create(...) if you are NOT using RSpec
user2 = create(:user)

photo = create(:photo, :user => user1, :image = >Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.join(Rails.root,'spec','GIV_jpg_file_small.jpg'))  )
comment = create(:comment, :photo => photo, :user => user2);
```

Well, I think you get the point :)